# SyntaxError when firing python scirpt in nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, shell, npm

I'm using python-shell package for nodejs to fire a python script, which return SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

**Nodejs code**

```
const options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python3',
    scriptPath: __dirname + '/script',
};
var pyshell = new PythonShell('test.py', options);

pyshell.send('hello');

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
  // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
  console.log(message);
});

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
pyshell.end(function (err,code,signal) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The exit code was: ' + code);
  console.log('The exit signal was: ' + signal);
  console.log('finished');
});
```

**Python script**

```
print(f'test')
```

**Error**

```
PythonShellError:   File "/app/src/back/script/test.py", line 1
print(f'meas')
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If i run the script, with the command : python3 test.py , i'm getting the word 'test' printed as excepeted, but not with the use of python-shell as i want to.
My python version is 3.8.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the exact error you would get with an older version of Python that doesn't support f-strings (3.5 or earlier).

Try running `/usr/bin/python3` on your system and see what version that is.

Comment: Turns out it was my docker container on which i'm running the whole thing that had an older version of Python